# Mounting 32Tb RAID Volume Causes Server To Crash

Tags: hardware-raid, ntfs, raid5

I have a 32Tb NTFS RAID 5 volume. 5x8tb SATA, LSI 9361i+Supercap.

Was working fine until it started behaving strange on day - drive name vanished and data seemed to vanish. Then rebooted, Windows 10, wanted to do a check when booting but I skipped it. Data seemed to be there, but then after reboots, windows just crashes.

If I disconnect the drives Windows boots fine, then if I hot plug them and import the foreign configuration, Windows crashes in a few seconds. I booted into a Linux live CD, that almost boots but crashes.

Any ideas how I can access this volume to try and recover data if just mounting it crashes in Windows and Linux?

OS is just Windows 10 because I have not finished properly setting up the server. I migrated data from old server to this and never got round to installing Server 2019. The linux distro is actually an older Acronis Live CD.

I disconnected one drive from the RAID and plugged in another drive, RAID controller is happy to rebuild the volume, so it seems like file system corruption rather than a hardware issue.

I've moved drives around to check it's not a backplane fault. I also have 6x8tb SATA set up as RAID 6 which are working fine which seems to rule out all hardware issues.

Comment: Don't know 'bout windows, but "linux crashes" - what exactly do you see? Did you managed to capture dmesg logs of that crash?

Comment: Hardware or driver, and not enough info for us to help. There is no way that it is the OS crashing without either the hardware or the driver helping - no current os is that buggy.

Comment: Sorry it's just an Acronis live CD so it isn't saving any logs. Win 10 had some minidump files i was going to look at, but when I booted windows fine and realised mounting the volume is what causes Windows to crash, I realised something strange is up with this volume.

Comment: Use any useful live CD. I've seen too many problems spawned from using Acronis so I am not considering it as a serious tool.

Comment: I'd suspect a LSI card as a cause here. Try to use another LSI card, possibly another model — it should still be able to import the array. Try to connect drives directly to Linux; LSI often uses SNIA DDF on-disk format which Linux MD RAID also recognizes and it't able to assemble and work with it.

Comment: Tried a few Ubuntu and Knoppix live USB, saw the volume in the file managers, but could if I clicked it, I got errors saying the volume could not be mounted. Tomorrow going to try connecting the drives to an LSI HBA to see if the LSI controller is the problem

Comment: Jun 1 08:10]mount.ntfs[8754]:segfault at 0 ip 00007fb7754f4f94 sp 00007ffe64ffccc0 error 4 in libntfs-3d.so.o-
883.0.0[7fb7754D7000+37000]
[  +0.000012]Code: ff ff 00 00 55 49 21 f4 53 48 83 ec 18 48 85 ff 0f 84 40 02 00 00 48 83 3f 00 48 89 fb 75 67 4c 8b 47 10 49 8b 80 98 00 00 00 <48> 8b 10 48 85 d2 0f 84 80 01 00 00 48 8b 7a 10 48 85 ff 74 3c 41

Comment: Connected it via HBA, Ubuntu sees the volume name but can't mount it. DMESG log above.